# node.js / react Upload file with graphql createReadStream is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, graphql, fs

I am trying to send a file (image) from my client app (react) to server(node.js).
I am getting the error : `TypeError: createReadStream is not a function`

This is my code:

graphql schema:

```
  type File {
    filename: String!
    mimetype: String!
    enconding: String!
  }
  extend type Mutation {
    singleUpload(file: Upload!): File!
}
```

graphql resolver:

```
module.exports = {
  Mutation: {
    async singleUpload(_, { file }) {
      try {
        const { createReadStream, filename } = await file;
        const stream = createReadStream();
        const pathName = path.join(__dirname, `/src/image/${filename}`);
        await stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(pathName));
        return file;
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return err;
      }
    },
}
```

apolloServer:

```
const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  context,
  introspection: true,
  playground: {
    settings: {
      "schema.polling.enable": false,
      "editor.fontSize": 18,
    },
  },
});
```

appClient

```
const appClient = new ApolloClient({
  link: createUploadLink({ uri: baseURL + "/graphql" }),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

const SINGLE_UPLOAD = gql`
  mutation singleUpload($file: Upload!) {
    singleUpload(file: $file) {
      filename
      mimetype
      enconding
    }
  }
`;
const [userImage, setUserImage] = useState();

  const handleSubmit = (event: any) => {
    uploadFile({ variables: { file: userImage } });
}
```

While debugging the file object I get in the server it looks like **C://fakeadress/name.jpg**

Do you have any ideea why I am getting this error?

I am using the latest version of all modules.

Comment: no file sent, only filename?  check network request body - for upload it should be form-data encoded, not usual json query+variables

Comment: Thanks for the asnwer. I think that is the issue...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working:

```
const [file, setFile] = useState({});
const [uploadFile] = useMutation(UploadMutation);

const handleSubmit = async () => {
    if (file) {
      uploadFile({
        variables: { file },
        // add the rest of the form fields to this query
        // refetchQueries: [{ query: FileQuery, variables: file }],
      });
      setFile({});
      // post message on form
      console.log("Uploaded successfully: ", file);
    } else {
      // return alertk
      console.log("No files to upload");
    }
  };

const { getRootProps, getInputProps } = useDropzone({
    accept: "image/*",
    onDrop: (acceptedFile) => {
      setFile(
        Object.assign(acceptedFile[0], {
          preview: URL.createObjectURL(acceptedFile[0]),
        })
      );
    },
  });

<div {...getRootProps({ className: "dropzone" })}>
                <input {...getInputProps()} />
                <p>Drag 'n' drop some file here, or click to select file</p>
              </div>
```

Comment: so the problem was on the frontend? nothing wrong with the backend code?